# wget mangling output written to stdout, works only with -q

Tags: linux, wget, xterm, gnome-terminal

I have a minimal HTTP server written in python (http://pastebin.com/mjLDk7Gk) that simply answers every GET request with status 200 and body "Done".

If I do

```
wget "http://localhost:9001" -O - -q
Done
```

But if I leave out the -q:

```
wget "http://localhost:9001" -O - 
--2015-01-12 15:28:20--  http://localhost:9001/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:9001... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

  [<=>                                                               ] 0           --.-K/s              D
  [ <=>                                                              ] 4           --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-01-12 15:28:20 (670 KB/s) - written to stdout [4]
#blank line here
```

At the end of the first "status bar" line there is a "D", it is in fact the first character of the desired output. I assume that the output is somewhere lost while refreshing the terminal. This also happens with longer response bodys.

Another observation: If I redirect the output to a file, it works again:

```
 wget "http://localhost:9001" -O -  > /tmp/file
 cat /tmp/file
 Done
```

It also happens with very wide terminals. The "status bar" is growing, but there's still only one character of the response body.

Is this a bug or a configuration fault somewhere on my side? I get identical behavior with gnome-terminal and xterm (on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS).

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the terminal truncating instead of wrapping the output?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On one hand, with `-O -`, you are requesting `wget` to write the received data in `stdout`, which it does **without buffering**.
On the other hand, and unless you suppress it whith `-q`, `wget` writes progress informations in `stderr`.

If you don't redirect one of the streams (using `> some_file`), they are both displayed **simultaneously** by the terminal, and they don't mix well, specially since `wget` uses special characters to display the status bar.

What you expect is for `wget` to :

1. Retrieve the data and store it somewhere, while displaying progress status
2. Then, after everything has been retrieved, display the data.

You can do this with a temporary file :

```
wget "http://localhost:9001" -O /tmp/some_file && cat /tmp/some_file
```

You could also probably use [buffer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) :

```
wget "http://localhost:9001" -O - | buffer -b 1 -s 100000
```

Comment: I think you mean `stdout` in your first sentence? Apart from that, this all makes sense.

Comment: you are right. answer corrected